# Unity Rotate ball left or right insted of roll

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to learn Unity3D and I'm using this [tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-ball-tutorial) to get started.

In my `PlayerController` below the "ball" rolls in the direction of the arrow key pressing. But my question is: When I press left or right arrow I don't want it to move in the direction but to turn in the direction.

So the ball moves forward/backward on arrow key up/down and rotate left/right on arrow key left/right.

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed;

    private Rigidbody rb;
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

        rb.AddForce (movement * speed);

    }
}
```

I've searched on google but haven't been able to find a solution.

**UPDATE**
Here is my camera controller.

```
public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject player;
    private Vector3 offset;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        offset = transform.position - player.transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void LateUpdate () {
        transform.position = player.transform.position + offset;
    }
}
```

Comment: Read about transform.Rotate() [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html). This is what you probably want, but you need to also consider the camera rotation and set Vector3 to `Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (0.0f , 0.0f, moveVertical);` (or the other way around).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
float delta = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
Vector3 axis = Vector3.forward;

rb.AddTorque (axis * speed * delta);
```

or

```
transform.Rotate (axis * speed * delta);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
 rb.AddForce (movement * speed);
```

you can use:

```
 rb.AddTorque (movement * speed);
```

This will add angular force to the ball.